# Use previous value within a repeat group

Tags: commcare

Do you have a workaround on how to use a previous value of a variable within a repeat group in another variable in the repeat group without having a circular reference error? For example my user is supposed to enter a number of foods with different time of consumption but we also want to have the option to select type = same as previous. But when I'm trying to use the `time[x] = time[x-1]` where `x` is the current position I have circular reference error.

Answer (score 1):

I would need a bit more information about your configuration to properly design a solution, but I would suggest examining the following document on [repeat groups](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Using+Repeat+Groups+in+the+Form+Builder). In particular, I would examine the sections on the `..`, `current()` and `position()` functions. These are three functions used specifically for repeat groups that allow you to reference specific nodes that have been created by a repeat group. Based on your description, you could potentially use a combination of the `current()` function and the `position()` function to bypass this circular reference error. I hope this helps!